# Meaning-in-context of feature in: "all visible features of an area"

Tags: meaning-in-context

[Landscape definition as per Google](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&sxsrf=ALeKk00P_0y63FPxbixNuvGPktXlCWI4Rw%3A1600192971217&ei=ywFhX_zVDNSpmgeg5rvIBg&q=landscape%20meaning&oq=landscape%20me&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAxgAMgoIABCxAxBGEPkBMgIIADICCAAyAggAMgIIADICCAAyAggAMgIIADICCAAyAggAOgQIABBHOgcIABCxAxBDOgQIABBDOgUIABCxA1CSCliBDWC-E2gAcAJ4AIABjQGIAekCkgEDMC4zmAEAoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdpesgBCMABAQ&sclient=psy-ab)

> all the visible features of an area of land, often considered in terms of their aesthetic appeal.

Does the word *"features"* mean characteristics in this case?

Comment: Pablo, we have been through this. When you ask about a dictionary entry or a sentence from a passage, you need to type out the context. **Do not upload screenshots.**

Answer (score 1):

Features here denote *something that is perceivable or tangible*. For example: the trees, bushes, fences, mountains, etc. They may refer to the characteristics of the place it is referring to. Like in this case, the beauty of the surroundings or anything sort of that.